# Pay now once and, optionally (!), create a subscription too -- how to do this in Stripe?

Tags: go, stripe-payments

On a page there's a textbox where a customer or payer enters an amount to donate to me via Stripe, as one time payment. And there's also a checkbox "subscribe for $5/mo" which, if checked, would charge him that amount **afterwards**.

The thing is:

it's a one time payment **in any case** and charged immediatelly; a custom amount -- whaterver a customer enters. **And, optionally,** a customer would be charged $5/mo within a subscription, automatically, starting **in a month** - if, and only if, he checks a checkbox.

I know how to create a session for charging a customer one time, and here's code, partially:

```
    stripeParams := &stripe.CheckoutSessionParams{
        PaymentMethodTypes: stripe.StringSlice([]string{
            "card",
        }),

        LineItems: []*stripe.CheckoutSessionLineItemParams{
            &stripe.CheckoutSessionLineItemParams{
             PriceData: &stripe.CheckoutSessionLineItemPriceDataParams{
                 Currency: stripe.String(string(stripe.CurrencyUSD)),
                 ProductData: &stripe.CheckoutSessionLineItemPriceDataProductDataParams{
                     Name: stripe.String("test123"),
                 },
                 UnitAmount: stripe.Int64(amount * 100),
             },
             Quantity: stripe.Int64(1),
            },
        },
        Mode: stripe.String(string(stripe.CheckoutSessionModePayment)),

    //........
```

How would I implement the "plus a subscription of $5/mo on top" thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a Subscription through a Checkout Session you should follow this guide: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/checkout

To summarize, if you want to add a $5 subscription on top of the one-time payment amount entered by your customer you would do the following:

1. Create a Product and an associated $5 recurring Price in the [Dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/products?active=true) or the [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/create)
2. Change the Checkout Session from `mode: payment` to `mode: subscription` (see [apiref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-mode))
3. Add the Price ID you created in Step 1 and add it as an additional Line Item for the Checkout Session (see [apiref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items-price))
4. Set either `subscription_data.trial_end` ([apiref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-subscription_data-trial_end)) or `subscription_data.trial_period_days` ([apiref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-subscription_data-trial_period_days)) so that the recurring price is not charged until after the trial is over. The one-time price will still be charged upfront, even if the recurring price is on a trial.

If you don't want to use trials, you could also look into adding a one-time $5 [discount](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-discounts-coupon) to the Session.

Comment: That's not what I want. Re-read my question

Comment: Sorry about missing the part about not charging the recurring price until later - updated the answer.

Comment: but I want a one-time price to be $X, whereas a subscription which will become active  afterwards, to be of a different price - $Y. In your solution the price is $5 for one time payment and for a subscription too, right? Which is effectively the same as starting subscription without a free trial, and charging a customer immediately.

Comment: Nom=m for the solution I described you can have different prices for the one-time item and the subscription. You would have two line items - the one you already have defined in your code for the one-time price, and then an additional one that defines the recurring price (which I mention in step 3).